# Convert python launch arg to normal python variable

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to pass an argument to a python launch file and convert it to a normal in-built python type to use within the python launch file?

E.g. `ros2 launch my_launch_file.launch.py temp_arg:="some string"` and then

```
# my_launch_file.launch.py
str_arg = LaunchConfiguration("temp_arg")
print(type(str_arg)) # <class 'launch.substitutions.launch_configuration.LaunchConfiguration'>
# Instead, I would like the value of str_arg to be of type <class 'str'>
# NOTE: the code below doesn't work due to the type of str_arg
if (str_arg == "config1"):
  # some logic here
else:
  # some other logic here
```

The reason being that I want to use the `str_arg` var to do some other logic in the launch file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398894/convert-python-launch-arg-to-normal-python-variable/) by [jn42](https://answers.ros.org/users/85101/jn42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2022-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use e.g.

```
self.get_parameter("your_parameter").get_parameter_value().string_value
```

EDIT:

After the updated question - can you maybe use the `PythonExpression` substitution?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jn42](https://answers.ros.org/users/85101/jn42/) on 2022-04-11**:
I see the confusion. I modified the question to make it more clear that I want to use the argument within the *python launch file* and NOT a python node (I understand how to get the value of a parameter from within a node in ROS2)

**Comment by [jn42](https://answers.ros.org/users/85101/jn42/) on 2022-04-11**:
Should I rename the question title to something like "Convert LaunchConfiguration to inbuilt python type for python launch files"?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-11**:
Thanks, I updated the answer with a suggestion